# Python Equivalent to System('PAUSE')

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been coding a basic calculator in python 3.3 and I want to be able to run it in command window.

but as soon as i get to the end it shuts the windows before I have time to view the final answer.

so I was wondering if there is an equivalent to the c++ System('PAUSE') command to tell it not to go any further until the user is ready.

Here is my calculator code:

```
print('Your Very Own Basic Calculator')
first_num = int(input('Please Enter The First Number: '))
second_num = int(input('Please Enter The Second Number: '))
Equation = input('What would you like to do, multiplication, division, subtraction or     
if Equation == ('*'):
addition? *, /, -, +')
    print('The Answer is',first_num * second_num)
elif Equation == ("/"):
    print('The Answer is',first_num / second_num)
elif Equation == ('-'):
    print('The Answer is',first_num - second_num)
elif Equation == ('+'):
    print('The Answer is',first_num + second_num)
```

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `input()` on p3k or `raw_input()` on p2.7x - it will read anything from stdin, so it will wait until user is ready.

Comment: what I am going to do is just add in a While loop in so that when it gets to the end it asked if you want to do another sum so you can see what it was whilst you decide if you want to enter another sum. i should have thought of it before, my bad :/ but thanks @FilipMalczak

Answer (score 11):

as of today  this is working under win7 :

```
import os
(...)
os.system("PAUSE")
```

Watch out the caps in the snippet, pause is not PAUSE.

Comment: This function much like the one from @S1lur is Windows specific, linux/unix distros will throw an error

Answer (score 8):

```
import time

time.sleep(secs)
```

The other option is better, but this answers Your question too.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
...
os.system("pause")
```

this should do the job

Comment: `sh: 1: pause: not found`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program to do math with,
A.  "input()" that basically wait's for the user to input a value and based on that value calculates the result, also u will see 
B. While True: meaning the program never stops (or at least the user inputs 2 than asked to exit) 
Finally some part is on Greek lang. (u will need to translate them)

```
import os

# Reads a Float number
def read(thesi):
    try:
        ask_me = f'Δώσε μου τον {thesi} αριθμό'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        number_a = float(input())
        return number_a
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Ζητήθηκε άμεση έξοδος από το πρόγραμμα')
        quit()
    except ValueError:
        print('Σφάλμα:')
        return read(thesi)

def continue_exit():
    try:
        accept_only = ('1', '2')
        ask_me = '1. Continue   2. Exit the Program'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        number= input()
        if number in accept_only:
            return number
        else:
            print('Try again')
            return continue_exit()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Ζητήθηκε άμεση έξοδος από το πρόγραμμα')
        quit()
    except ValueError:
        print('Σφάλμα:')
        return continue_exit()

# Reads the type of the equation
def equation_read():
    lst = ['+', '-', '/', '*', 'mod', 'pow', 'div']
    ask_me = f'μαθηματική πράξη?'
    os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
    print('Input --> +  -  /  * mod pow div ')
    equation = input()
    if equation in lst:
        return equation
    print('Σφάλμα')
    return equation_read()


# Checks and does the math
def math(a ,b ,eq):
    forbiden_zero_division = ('/', 'mode', 'div')
    if b == 0 and eq in forbiden_zero_division:
        ask_me = f'Σφάλμα: Δεν επιτρέπεται διαίρεση με το 0'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        return 'Division by 0!'
    if eq == '+':
        ask_me = f'Ζητήθηκε πρόσθεση:'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        return a + b
    elif eq == '-':
        ask_me = f'Ζητήθηκε αφαίρεση:'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        return a - b
    elif eq == '/':
        ask_me = f'Ζητήθηκε διαίρεση:'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        return a / b
    elif eq == '*':
        ask_me = f'Ζητήθηκε πολλαπλασιασμός:'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        return a * b
    elif eq == 'mod':
        ask_me = f'Ζητήθηκε το υπόλοιπο διάιρεσης:'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        return a % b
    elif eq == 'pow':
        ask_me = f'Ζητήθηκε η δύναμη:'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        return a ** b
    elif eq == 'div':
        ask_me = f'Ζητήθηκε ακέραιη διαίρεση:'
        os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
        return a // b


while True:
    a = read('πρώτο')  # Read the First Number
    b = read('δεύτερο')  # Read the Second Number
    eq = equation_read()  # Read the Type of the equation
    result = math(a, b, eq) # Do the math
    print(result)
    ask_me = f'Αποτέλεσμα {result}'
    os.system(f"say '{ask_me}'")
    c_e = continue_exit()
    if c_e == '2':
        break
```