# Python Executable how to on Windows

Tags: python, windows, executable

I'm running windows

I've got a python script that works as expected when I run it from my interpreter (Anaconda, i think that's an interpreter...), but when I run it from my file manager by double clicking the script ("script.py") I see a quick black screen flash, but nothing else. I'm using the input() function, so that's not the issue.
When I try the same thing with a simple test script, which is just the print() function and the input function, the command line or terminal screen, whatever the black screen is called, displays my printed string and closes only after I press enter.
I believe my issue has to do with file paths and working directories, but I'm a noob and I don't know how to solve this. My script declares this variable:

inv_folder=r"C:\Users\domin\OneDrive\Desktop\Test Folder" #folder to look for completed recipe files

which I believe is an absolute filepath. I then loop through the files in that folder and open and read them

for filename in os.listdir(inv_folder):

Main goal is to send my script to someone else's computer, and allow them to run it simply by double clicking on the file. Trying to do that on my computer and failing

Comment: You'd better write the minimal reproducible code example, not just one line or put all your lines inside `try... except: input('error')` block and see if it will write something useful

Answer (score 0):

Doubleclicking the .py file in Windows will generally run the file. In your case, if all your script is doing is looking for a directory and looping through files in it, it is quite possible that the script is working correctly, but that it is closing immediately upon completing the script.

E.g. if you have the following python file hello.py with the single line of code.

```
print("hello world")
```

If you doubleclick hello.py, you will only see a black window flash for a second, as the program runs and exits.

To check whether your code is working correctly or not, you are best to navigate to that folder in your command prompt and run the program within the command prompt. E.g. typing "hello.py" in the right folder will then show the correct output in the console.

Try running it in the console first, seeing if the code is giving any errors, and then working from there. But the behaviour you are describing is basically standard Windows behaviour and not necessarily an error.

If you need to pause the window after running, please see the following StackOverflow question and answers about ["Python Equivalent to System('PAUSE')"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466398/python-equivalent-to-systempause)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to compile it?
You can compile it easily with [pyinstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) and this command:
`C:\<path_to_python>\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe --onefile -n <your script name> <your script path>`

Of course replace the <> with the relevant paths for you.